# "Connection reset by peer" error. asp.net IIS 7.5 windows server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, iis, https, tls1.2

I've disabled TLS 1.0 & 1.1 and enabled 1.2 and I'm getting this error "Connection reset by peer" when I access website hosted in IIS 7.5. Below are some info I used for troubleshooting but to no avail.

Browser connection uses "TLS 1.2, AES with 256 bit encryption (High); ECDH_P384 with 384 bit exchange".
Hash signature is "sha256RSA"

registry value for "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\SSL\00010003"

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_CK_RC4_128_WITH_MD5
SSL_CK_DES_192_EDE3_CBC_WITH_MD5

Comment: Learn how to analyze SSL/TLS handshake packets in tools like Wireshark, and then the culprit should be clear.

Comment: @LexLi This is happening on company network. They won't allow me to install anything. :(

Comment: the reason behind the error is the connection is taking too long to establish and hence the client is dropping it and trying to re-establish the connection. I suggest you go through How to enable SChannel event logging in IIS and modify the registry settings on your servers to enable SChannel logging. by following [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/260729/how-to-enable-schannel-event-logging-in-iis) you could enable schannel logging in iis. I suggest you could use [iis crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) to enable or disable protocols.

Comment: "They won't allow me to install anything", and then they should expect you can do nothing at all for them. Troubleshooting without the proper tools is not troubleshooting.

Comment: @LexLi Haha. Lot of requests, approvals will be required before deploying anything.  I'll have to try that. Thanks!

Comment: @Raj is your issue resolved?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Nope. Server is in intranet. Website is exposed thru LB where we have a ssl certificate installed. So the error might be the outcome of not having valid SSL certificate for the website to expose it from port 443 within intranet. I've been using self signed certificate. I've changed the port and it's now working without SSL over http.